# how to overcome tracking jitter

Tags: tracking, virtual-reality, jitter

I'm working with a object tracking project.

```
Steps:
1.Preprocessing the image and achieve some candidates regions of interest.
2.For each region, test if it is the target by ORB/BF.
3.After the target region determined, acquire coordinates of some points on the target and their corresponding coordinates in the world coordinate system.
4.Use solvePnP(in opencv) to get rotation vector and translation vector.
5.Translation vector is used in VR for localization and view control.
```

Tracking jitter means, although the object is stationary, because of some tracking errors, such as noise, the position of the target is slightly changing. Then, **look at step 4 and step 5**, due to the change, translation vector is slightly changed and with the Head Mounted Device, I feel the jitter all the time.
Seems to me that tracking jitter is unavoidable because of change in environment or some noise. But one pixel value change can lead to about a few centimeters change in z value in translation vector. So any proper way to deal with it?

I have googled but there didn't seem much information.[Effects of Tracking Technology, Latency, and Spatial Jitter on Object Movement](http://www.yorku.ca/mack/3dui2009.html) mentions the phemomenon, but did not provide a solution. Another interesting paper is [Motion Tracking Requirements and Technologies](http://minnow.cc.gatech.edu/ael/uploads/38/Motion%20Tracking%20Survey%20Chapter.pdf). So can anyone offer some useful information?
It occurs to me that fileter is needed to do some post processing to the tracking data. But the idea is not very idea. Kalman filter can be used for tracking and can be used to attenuate noise. I don't know whether it can compensate for this kind of jitter(I mean, very small fluctuation in values) very well. And investigate how to incorporate Kalman filter into this project is another topic and need extra time.

Comment: My guess would be to do a little more preprocessing on each individual image to remove noise due to low image quality, using something like [this filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering) and in addition, using PID techniques on the raw video feed to sort of interpolate "expected" image frames and reduce jitter by smoothing the video feed to be more stable overall.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you very much for your suggestion. I read the link but I did not find much information about anisotropic filter. I read from some posts and paper that interpolating is an option, but I don't know how, or what PID tech is. I'm sure your ideas bring me inspiration and point something interesting.

Comment: [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller)